# How can I capture URL parameters sent to a google form, and save them to the connected spreadsheet?

Tags: url, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, url-parameters

I have 2 scripts - one to fire on open trigger, and one to fire on save, I'm not sure which one would work best with function scope etc...
But basically, users are sent to the survey form using a public link, and additional info is added to that link in the form of parameters/queries, such as:

```
booking=123456
start-at=1429952400
item=1702
```

I'm trying to have the script save these parameters, or even the entire URL that was used to open the form, preferably on the same row as the survey response, but even if the user doesn't submit the form, I would still like to save the URL as a non-completed survey (hence the on-open and on-save triggers).

I looked into:

```
function doGet(e) {}, 
function URL(text) {}, 
function doPost(e) {}, 
even console.log(params); and console.log(e);
```

as well as others and I cannot seem to get access to the URL.

What gives? Should I just code this on my own server and run my own form? I would really like to figure out google scripting but it seems just too cumbersome at this point. Any help or solution would be highly appreciated.

To be clear, I don't think I can use a pre-filled url, because I don't know that parameter values ahead of time, and I don't think you can use hidden fields for pre-filled anyway.

Comment: Short answer is you can't, but maybe there is an alternate solution; difficult to say based on your current question.  Why you can't access them has been asked many times, for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21554204/how-do-you-get-url-parameters-in-a-google-form-using-google-apps-script).  I think you misunderstand what [`doPost(e)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) is for.  You can achieve what you want if you put the form in a web app (also many SO question about that).

Answer (score 1):

From the question

> What gives? Should I just code this on my own server and run my own form? I would really like to figure out google scripting but it seems just too cumbersome at this point. Any help or solution would be highly appreciated.
>
> To be clear, I don't think I can use a pre-filled url, because I don't know that parameter values ahead of time, and I don't think you can use hidden fields for pre-filled anyway.

A prefilled-url could be used to set the answers to all the questions in a Google Form.

Please bear in mind that Google Forms doesn't support hidden questions in the sense of an HTML form does, the way that you could do this is by putting the question on a section that the form response flow never show it but on the prefill view all the sections are displayed.

Regarding using Google Apps Script to handle Google Forms a custom URL query string that is not supported, so if that is a deal-breaker, then you should use other options.

If you like so much Google Apps Script you could use it to create a web application as `doGet` pass the URL query string / parameters to the server side code and also you could grab them from the client-side code by using the HTML Service.