# Is it possible to set getRespondentEmail value in script-created response for google form?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-forms, email-validation

Created a issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/220585485) and [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/221095123) for this. Consider adding a star(on the top left), if you'd like this issue resolved as well

---

I'm working on some qa stuff for our workflow.

As a part of it I want to automate submission of test forms to check if they processed correctly.

The thing is, the form is collecting emails, and I have no idea how to set them from script.

I've created a minimalistic(really!) example of form, which is collecting EMAIL ONLY.

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1Ve12XWUxYH9U1cBPwAmgLbWdA8S3lnEkqgosTbqlOLg/edit?usp=sharing

The code I'm running is

```
function createDummyFormResponse() {
  var form = FormApp.openById('1Ve12XWUxYH9U1cBPwAmgLbWdA8S3lnEkqgosTbqlOLg');
  var response = form.createResponse();
  
  response.submit();      
}
```

Doesn't work with error

```
5:08:26 PM  Error Exception: Invalid data updating form.
            createDummyFormResponse@ qa.gs:45
```

Apparently I don't expect it to work, cause I haven't set respondent email anywhere.
I thoroughly enough(I hope) studied Form and Response reference and I see nothing about setting respondent email in script-created form.

Is it possible at all and does anyone know how it can be done?

Comment: If you share Google drive files, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Comment: Create a feature request in the issue tracker. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for  official documentation, free resources and more details.

Comment: You may be able to reproduce this client side -> see the post request made in browser dev tools -> recreate the request using [tag:urlfetch]

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/220585485

Comment: You should create a feature request for `setRespondentEmail()` method( similar to `getRespondentEmail()`). Your question here is clearer than the bug report you made.

Answer (score 1):

Currently it will use the users Email, but you can instead just add a text field called Email and then you can pre-populate it.

So if you want to fix it,  turn off the `Collect email addresses`. Then the field Email will be removed. Add a new field called Email and type text. Read the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21554204/how-do-you-get-url-parameters-in-a-google-form-using-google-apps-script) and then you should be able to prefill that field.

[image]

Comment: If email defaults to mine, why I'm getting 'Invalid data updating form.' then? I cannot submit absolutely empty form

Comment: Because you are programatically taking over the default functionality and trying to submit an empty form using your code. That results in the error, i.e. empty response. So I think there is a difference between having an Email field there which should be populated when using the UI vs submitting an empty form and assuming that somehow that Email is captured.

Comment: Yeah, if I convert email to simple field, everything works fine. Though it would require changing many forms and existing flow, so I would like to know it's impossible for sure before considering patching everything

Comment: If it works fine then it is possible. There should not be a problem in any script.

Answer (score 1):

The original poster has created a feature request on Google issue tracker:

Created a issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/221095123) for this and [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/220585485) [closed].

Consider adding a star(on the top left), if you'd like this issue resolved as well

Answer (score 0):

For now, the only workaround is as proposed by @Neven
Appropriate code(disables email collecting and create similar Email Text input on top of form):

```
function disableEmailCollect(formId) {
    var form = FormApp.openById(formId);
    form.setCollectEmail(false);

    if(form.getItems()[0].getTitle() !== 'Email') { // Just to check we haven't done that already
      var validation = FormApp.createTextValidation().setHelpText('Please provide your contact email.').requireTextIsEmail().build();  // Init Email Validation
      var newItem = form.addTextItem().setTitle('Email').setValidation(validation).setRequired(true);
  
      form.moveItem(newItem.getIndex(),0); // Move to top
    }  
}
```