# can't populate email field when submitting response to google form by script

Tags: google-apps-script

I develop a standalone google script project (published as web app) where I have to programmatically answer to a google form I own. 
There are only text and list type of question in my gform so the code is :

```
     var FormResponse = gform.createResponse();      
  var questions = gform.getItems();     
  for(i=0;i<questions.length;i++) {
    var question = questions[i];
    var label=question.getTitle();     
    var valeur =rep[label];
    if (question.getType()=="TEXT") {
     qr = question.asTextItem().createResponse(valeur);
     FormResponse.withItemResponse(qr);
    }
    else if (question.getType()=="LIST") {
       qr = question.asListItem().createResponse(valeur);  
      FormResponse.withItemResponse(qr);          
    }        
  }

  FormResponse.submit();
```

works like a charme, but for the "email address" which doesn't appear in the list of questions.
It's because I chose the "collect emails" parameter in my gform and I want to keep this parameter. 
Obviously I can - always using script - insert the email address in the gsheet bounded to the gform. But the email address won't be in the responses embedded in the gform, and for instance the prefilled form for that particular response won't have the prefilled email address.
Does anyone can confirm this behaviour and explain the logic ? Is there a workaround ? Thanks.

Comment: You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26425627/retrieve-the-e-mail-address-of-a-google-form-respondent-without-asking-for-their) which stated that you can use [`getRespondentEmail()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getRespondentEmail()) to retrieve the submitter's email address. You may also check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342684/hidden-field-in-a-google-form) for additional information.

Comment: thank for your answer. 
The point  is that I don't want to retrieve the mail of a person who responded to my form but to programmaticallay fill and respond to my form. I want to set the respondentEmail address not to get it.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: no, i didn't. I realized it was a feature, deeply linked to the logic of google form/spreadsheet. you can't programmatically populate the email address (=google account). Only the user can manually does it.