# Google forms pre-filed url and "hidden"page

Tags: google-forms

I'm trying to pass some variables into a form using a pre-filed url. I don't want users to be able to edit those values.

I thought I'd be able to "cheat ": create a pre-filled url, put the values on a separate page, and then skip that page when the user submits (in other words, they'd complete page 1 and continue to page 3; page 2 has the values.

The only problem is that, when the page is skipped, the url doesn't pre-fill.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing has changed in this area since [the last time this was asked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20355294/1677912); I wish it had. One other thought would be to generate an HTML form that mimics the Google Form but includes your variables in hidden fields; then submit the whole shabang in the background.

Answer (score -2):

What @mogsdad mentioned on the comment is correct.

Still. I believe that both you and @kira (at [Hidden Field in a Google form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342684/hidden-field-in-a-google-form)) can achieve what you want because you do NOT initially plan to hide the field.
What you are asking for is to simply **prevent users from altering the prefilled fields**.

You:

> I don't want users to be able to edit those values.

@kira:

> ...put up help text asking the user not to modify this field.

Even user @wbt in his question (https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79956/) mentions:

> ...but I'd like to then make that field hidden to help not confuse
>   people who are filling out the form

If I read your question correctly, there is a solution to your problem.

---

**To prevent users from altering a prefilled question/field** (and not actually hide it).

- Create a question.

  1. **Make the answer multiple choice with just one option**.
  2. **Make the answer required**.
- Repeat 1. and 2. for as many questions as you like.
- Prefill the fields.
- Share the prefilled link of the form.

Simple, straightforward solution.
@manetsus and @puppetx : No scripts involved.

Comment: I tried this but was not able to change the pre-filled value for the multiple choice answer; changing the pre-fill value just meant that the answer wasn't selected by default. Could you give an example of how your suggestion should be used?

Comment: I can't do this, the multiple choice is defined beforehand you can't modify it when doing the pre-fill, only select it. It's not dynamic. Only works if the pre-filled data is the same for everyone which doesn't help me.

Comment: I agree @marikamitsos can you elaborate please? When you add a multiple choice question, you need to specify at lease one answer. But when you pass something else to that question via prefilling, only the original option gets displayed.