# Create a readonly question in google a form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Hello I'm currently using AppScript and I'm trying to fetch the whole page of my google form in order to get a certain value (set in prefill) by doing
`UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)` except that it gives me a simple page like :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=300, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <meta name="description" content="Create a new survey on your own or with others at the same time. Choose from a variety of survey types and analyze results in Google Forms. Free from Google.">
```

So I don't know if it's possible with a special link or an authorization to get all the content of a page

I did a lot of research and nobody wanted to do that, I try to do it in order to retrieve a value that would have been put in prefill from the url (and as I can't retrieve this link as it is modified directly) I try to retrieve the whole page and thanks to the id of the element I retrieve its original value and I reuse it later ^^

If someone has an idea ? :)

**Edit 1 :**

 Objective :
Create a google form with one readonly question, the value of this question corresponds to the id of the discord account that is obtained through a pre-filled link

- Now I can fetch a form url like 
  `UrlFetchApp.fetch(FormApp.getPublishedUrl())`
  But if we do that, we only have an empty form
- We also can fetch a form url like 
  `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.ID=VALUE)`
   But we can't know the url who use the person when she clicks on the link
- I also see this url : `url/formResponse` but the problem is the same, we can't get the complete url :/

Comment: Are you doing this in a macro function within a google sheet or are you doing this from a server you wrote?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. From the HTML included it looks that you are using the wrong URL. Please add a [mcve] and add more details about why do are looking to scrape data from a form that you own.

Comment: Hey @zipzit, I don't have any Google Sheet, Im doing this request directly in my function

Comment: Hello @Rubén, the final objective is to create a readonly question, or a question whose answer cannot be changed in a general way. So in first you need to create a Google Form and create a little script like that :

```var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
console.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch(form).getContentText())```

Little update : I have access to the source code when I do that now (I don't know why but okay)

Comment: So now I have a problem, I can fetch this url (incredible) and I can fetch a prefilled url it's okay. But now I can't know what's the value of the prefilled url ?
I use a Discord button to create this url like that : `google.form.../entry.XXX=Discord_ID`
I don't know if it's possible to get the url who use the person for complete my google form, I found nothing about that :x

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add to it all the relevant details.

Comment: Okay Im new on stackoverflow sorry and thanks for your response :D

Answer (score -1):

Pre-filling data within Google Forms dynamically can be achieved in the following way:

- Open your form in editor mode
- Click the kebab menu (the three vertical dots) to the top right and select the option "Get pre-filled link"
- When the new tab loads, just start filling in the fields with random data and click "Get Link" at the bottom
- Paste the link into a text editor. You'll notice there're key/value pairs associated with each field
- You may now manipulate the value for each key and form a new, pre-filled URL for your use

You may find this [video helpful](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vcEju__MPtw).

To load the form within an external webpage, you might want to use the iframe that can be generated upon clicking "Send." You may then update the src attribute with your pre-filled URL.

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer.

I will try to re-explain my problem:

Currently I am creating a link with a text field that is pre-populated with the value I want.
I use the "Open form" trigger to activate my function directly.

The purpose of my function is to retrieve the value that has been pre-filled in order to modify a regex

Because I can't know the value if the form is not post ?

Comment: Hi Tweenty_, I'm sorry - I didn't understand this part "...in order to modify a regex Because I can't know the value if the form is not post ?" From what I understand, you are already pre-filling the text field, but have trouble with form submission - is that right?

Comment: So I send a form that asks for my id (this id is pre-filled)

We have ID = 123456 and a regex is associated to this id so that nobody can "modify" the regex:
(?:^|\W)ID(?:$|\W) so I want (?:^|\W)123456(?:$|\W) and I found a solution (maybe) if I use https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/<ID>/formResponse?entry.ID=Value

Im gonna try this !

Comment: I see. So you need to prevent modifications to the regex that's associated to the pre-filled text field? I'm not sure if there's a solution for that kind of a problem. Hope that works!

Comment: So the url is not changed but I still can't read it haha, do you know if it's possible to get the url directly from the page where the person is?

And for "So you need to prevent modifications to the ID in the pre-filled text field?" it's that !

Comment: Are you able to access the instance of FormApp (then this might help: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app#getActiveForm()) or Form (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getId())?

Comment: Yep I already do that, but I don't find the url, I only find the shot url (shortenFormUrl), the analyse url (getSummaryUrl), the public url (getPublishedUrl) and the editor url (getEditUrl)

Comment: Dang. I suspect you'll have to persist the URL (in a Google Sheet, if your submissions are saved to a Sheet) to be able to access it. Otherwise, you'd have to construct it on the fly.

Comment: With the formResponse link you can see the default values but I can't analyze it and I don't use google sheet :/

(I have a webhook that returns an embed discord)

Comment: I just want to do a read only question xD

Comment: I found the solution here with hidden question !!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364235/google-form-make-answer-field-readonly

Comment: Annnd, it's doesn't work xD