# getResponses from an edited form with skipped sections

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a form with the starting section that ask what do you want to do:

Section 1

Question: What do you want do to?

- Response A
- Response B

In case of Response A the user land to Section 2

Section 2

Question: Insert your name:

[text box]

and then SUBMIT

In case of Response B the user land to Section 3

Question: Insert your surname:

[text box]

and then SUBMIT

I send the edit url of the form to the users email, and they have to complete adding their name or surname editing the form.

Now when the user re-submit the form editing it, inside getResponses there aren't the item inside the section filled the first time but skipped during the edit. Is it by design or there's a different way to extract it?

Example:

The user choose Response A => Section 2 => Insert the name => SUBMIT
getResponses include only "Insert your name:" item.

then

The user use the edit link, and choose Response B => Section 3 => Insert the surname => SUBMIT
getResponses include only "Insert your surname:" item.

I was aspecting that the SUBMIT during an edit resend all the items already filled.

In case is not, it the only solution to pull this "old" data from the response sheet, or there's another way?

Comment: is this still the actual situation?
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/20355294/3657200 (see point 2)

Comment: This is a bug.  When pages in the Form do not get filled out during an edit, Google Forms deletes the original answers.  I think there is already an issue filed in the [Link to Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open)  You'll need to search for it.  If you can't find it, then submit a new issue.