# Form does not respond

Tags: google-apps-script

According to an answer of this question ([Hidden field in a Google Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342684/hidden-field-in-a-google-form)) I made a simple form with only one page (section). I copied the source code of the form (from the source code of the published URL). I made a web app with

```
function doGet(e){
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index").evaluate();
}
```

The index.html file has the copied source code of the form.
When I call the web app url it appears the form but the question's html elements do not respond.

Comment: Does it create a new `HtmlOuput` object?

Comment: What you mean? You can try it just in seconds... make a simple one question google form. Published and take the url. Get the source code of this url and copied to a new index.html file in a google apps script project. Add the previous doGet() to the Code.js of the apps script project. Get the web app url of the apps script project and try it.